# Use of count in Oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a query which gives two column. one is of the organization id and one is of person id. Now I want that those organizations should be retrieved which returns more than one person id.

How can I modify my below query by using count tht this can be retrieved

Query :-

```
  select papf.person_id person_id,
          hoi.organization_id


    From   hr_organization_information hoi
          ,per_all_people_f papf  
    where  hoi.org_information2 = papf.person_id
    And    hoi.organization_id = 400
    and    sysdate between papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date
    group by person_id,organization_id
```

Output

```
Person_id  organization_id
123        400
678        400
```

So now how can I apply count in such a manner that having count(*) >1 can be used in the above query? That this organization_id will be fetched

```
      select count(PERSON_ID)
      FROM (
      select papf.person_id person_id,
      hoi.organization_id


From   hr_organization_information hoi
      ,per_all_people_f papf  
where  hoi.org_information2 = papf.person_id
And    hoi.organization_id = 400
and    sysdate between papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date
group by person_id,organization_id
-- having count(*)>1
 )
```

I Tried the above given query. But am not being able to use having in it. Also this is just returning the count. I need to retrieve the organization_id as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select unique hoi.organization_id
from          hr_organization_information hoi,
              per_all_people_f papf  
where         hoi.org_information2 = papf.person_id
and           hoi.organization_id = 400
and           sysdate between papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date
having        count(papf.person_id)>1;
```

This will return one row with only the organization_id for the organization with an id of 400 having more than one person.

Comment: Nice to see someone who knows that there is a synonym of `distinct` keyword. :) But I think this query will give an error. Although `having` can be used without `group by` clause there has to be aggregates in select list not ordinal columns even with an `unique` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all `organization_id` of organizations having more than one different `person_id` joined:

```
select hoi.organization_id, 
       count(distinct papf.person_id) pers_count
  from hr_organization_information hoi, per_all_people_f papf
 where hoi.org_information2 = papf.person_id
   and sysdate between papf.effective_start_date and
       papf.effective_end_date
 group by organization_id
having count(distinct papf.person_id) > 1
```

Just a note: shouldn't you add to your query `information_type` condition as well? As far as I remember columns content depends on defined type of information stored.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  hoi.organization_id,count(papf.person_id)
From   hr_organization_information hoi inner join per_all_people_f papf  
on hoi.org_information2 = papf.person_id
where   hoi.organization_id = 400
and    sysdate between papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date
group by hoi.organization_id having count(papf.person_id)>1;
```